# Fabric and AppPulse Conflict on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric

My problem is that I am trying to have two tools for gathering statistics and crash information for my project, these tools are Fabric and AppPulse

I added Fabric successfully and crashes is showing on Fabric dashboard, but when I tried to add AppPulse I start to get this message from Fabric on Xcode console:

> [Fabric] Unable to complete settings download Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/com.cloudappers.RTA/settings,
>   NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Move ), NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/caosx01/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7C34D924-FC6E-4EF1-BD1B-0D16F44555D0/data/Containers/Data/Application/CF895D58-2844-4A8A-8EDE-BC092033E944/Library/Caches/io.fabric.sdk.ios.data/com.cloudappers.RTA/settings.json,
>   NSFilePath=/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/com.cloudappers.RTA/settings,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdb84890d80 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

and I didn't receive any crashes from both tools after adding them together to the project.

I asked AppPulse support team and they recommended to disable crash capturing in hprummonitor.plist file:

```
<key>disableCrashReport</key>
<true/>
```

but after trying the recommended solution I still have the same log message.

Please any suggestion or solution or do I missing any thing here?

Comment: Hi Ammar, Todd from Fabric. Which are you initiating first? You can try reversing the order. Also clean your project when you make these changes. Thanks and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Thanks Todd, I will give it a shot and let you now the result :)